# Spring Service class is null

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm developing a Spring boot application, but I cannot understand why I'm getting an auto wired service null...

I have this class, marked with @Component annotation

```
@Component
public class Rele {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Pin pin;
    private GpioController gpio;
    private static GpioPinDigitalOutput relePin;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Rele.class);
    private Interruttore interruttore;
    @Autowired AccensioneService accensioneService;

    public Rele(){

    }

    // Costruttore
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public Rele(Pin pin, Interruttore interruttore) {
        this.pin = pin;
        this.gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        this.relePin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(pin, "MyRele", PinState.LOW);
        this.interruttore = interruttore;
    }

    public void lightOn() {
        if (relePin.isLow()) {
            relePin.high();
            updateAccensione(interruttore, true);
            logger.debug("Rele acceso");
        }
    }

    public void lightOff() {
        if (relePin.isHigh()) {
            relePin.low();
            updateAccensione(interruttore, false);
            logger.debug("Rele spento");
        }
    }

    public void updateAccensione(Interruttore interruttore, boolean acceso) {

        Date lastDateAccensione = new Date();

        try {
            logger.debug("AccensioneService is"+accensioneService.toString());
        lastDateAccensione = accensioneService.findLastDate(interruttore);
        } catch(NullPointerException npe){
            logger.debug("Accensione service è: "+accensioneService);
            logger.error("ECCOLO:", npe);
            lastDateAccensione = new Timestamp(lastDateAccensione.getTime());

        }
        Accensione accensione = new Accensione();
        Date date = new Date();
        logger.debug("lastDate:" + lastDateAccensione);
        accensione.setDateTime(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        accensione.setInterruttore(interruttore);
        accensione.setIsLit(acceso);
        accensione.setLastDateTime(lastDateAccensione);
        logger.debug("Accensione è:"+accensione.toString());
        accensioneService.saveAccensione(accensione);

    }
}
```

`accensioneService`uses `accensioneDao`to perform basic DB operations on the model Accensione.java. Using dao/services goes good in every controller I have.

In this case, Rele.java it's not a @Controller annotated class (because it's not a controller), so I annotated it via @Component to make it scanned by Spring, but I'm getting always a NullPointerException because accensioneService is null.

I use accensioneService also in another controller, and it works normally, I cannot understand why Spring does not recognize it in this class...

Thanks to @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu I understood that the problem was in how i created the Rele object.  The problem now is how to change the application to achieve the goal.

I have a ReleManager class which contains a map I need to know if a particular Rele has been already instantiated. I autowire Rele in this class to create it.

```
@Component
public class ReleManager {
    @Autowired Rele rele;
    private  final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReleManager.class);
    private Map<Pin, Rele> mappa = new HashMap<Pin, Rele>();

    public  Rele getRele(Pin pin, Interruttore interruttore){
        if(mappa.containsKey(pin) && mappa.get(pin)!=null){
            logger.debug("rele già instanziato");
            return mappa.get(pin);
        } else {
            logger.debug("rele da instanziare");
        rele.setInterruttore(interruttore);
        rele.setPin(pin);
        mappa.put(pin, rele);
        return rele;
        }
    }

}
```

This class is used in a controller method, this is the interesting part. I autowire ReleManager and Rele in this class to use the map above.

```
rele = releManager.getRele(RaspiPin.getPinByName(relePin), interruttore);
        if(lit){
        rele.lightOn();
        } else {
        rele.lightOff();
        }
```

lightOn() method is in Rele.class... now my NullPointerException comes when calling `if (relePin.isLow()) {` so now `relePin`is null...

Comment: How are you getting reference to `Rele` object in your app? Are you using `new` operator or using `spring`?

Comment: check the spring config if the package of this class is included for component scan

Comment: is AccensioneService annotated with Component, Service or Repository annotations?

Comment: AccensioneServiceImpl, which is the concrete implementation of AccensioneService is annotated with @Service("accensioneService"). Now I'm looking into how role is created, because maybe the error is there...

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I think you got the problem, I edited the original question because i'm getting nowhere trying to change how to create Rele